# Unable to update extension config values

Tags: bolt-cms

I've created a Bolt extension with a config.yml file:

```
app_id:
app_secret:
```

And I've set up a test route that just returns the config values:

```
public function initialize() {

    $this->app->get('example', array($this, 'example'))
        ->bind('example');
}

public function getName()
{
    return "name";
}

public function example()
{
    $response = $this->app->json($this->config);
    return $response;
}
```

And I get back:

```
{
  "app_id": null,
  "app_secret": null
}
```

Which is fine, but then if I change these values so that 'config.yml' is now:

```
app_id: 7sdf119sdfsdf508271357
app_secret: esdfsdfc0sdfsdfa70ce0deccaf81d6ec8a2cd694a93
```

I still get the same output. Even if I change the config.yml keys and values completely, it still seems to read the same. Is it being cached somewhere? This is really confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

The extension will have a distribution config file `config.yml.dist` that gets copied to  the`app/config/extensions/` directory and can be edited there, either on the CLI or via a sub menu of Extend in the backend.